# Why isn't the image (in CSS) appearing on my HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am following a tutorial to improve my skills. So I don't have great knowledge with CSS and HTML.
My problem is that the following is shown in the tutorial and hero image needs to appear on the website. But it doesn't.

Anyone have recommendations on what I should try to do instead?

Here is the bit in my CSS file:

```
#hero-image {
height: 580px;
padding-top: 1px;
background: #e8eced url('../images/hero.jpg') no-repeat center;
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Verify the path to the image, and make sure it exists

Comment: Verify the path to the image **relative to .css file** if you use one.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine if you swap the image URL, the path must be incorrect. What's your directory look like?

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard this is the path to the image but it still doesn't show.

`background: #e8eced url(‘MacintoshHD/Users/cc/Desktop/Website/images/hero.jpg’) no-repeat center;`

Comment: That's the url from the very root of your system, not relative to the CSS file. Given that the image and the stylesheet are both in their own folders the URL you posted in the question should be working... which is why I asked to see the directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the element and select Inspect. On the styles right-click on the image link and open it in a new tab. It should tell you the URL it's using and double check if the path is correct.

If the image you're trying to use is hosted on the tutorial you're following then you need to provide an absolute path (includes `http://` or `https://`) otherwise your code is looking for an image relative to your file which is in your server.